# Why function returns unexecuted

Tags: javascript

If I write this code:

```
var foo = function (){
    var x = 5;  
    return (function (){ return x;})();
}
alert(foo());
```

it alerts 5, as intended. But, if I do not use IIFE:

```
var foo = function (){
    var x = 5;  
    return function (){ return x;};
}
alert(foo());
```

it alerts

```
function(){return x;}
```

I understand that in the first example IIFE runs and whatever it computes gets returned.BUT, if not using IIFE function returns without being executed.
Why is function returned before it is executed?

Comment: Because your code does not involve a call to the function. That's what the last `()` does in the working example.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Well… you explicitly `return function ...`; that returns a function. Which you're not calling. Unclear where the surprise is.

Comment: Ahaaa. Ok, another one: Is

Comment: So is function(){return x:}  which gets alerted in the second option a string?

Comment: No, it's a *function object*.

Comment: Did you mean to do `foo()()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions in JS are first class objects. You can treat them in the same way as you can treat any object, including pass them about between functions.

If you don't do something to call a function, then it doesn't get called.

> So is function(){return x:} which gets alerted in the second option a string

It is a function.

Functions, like any object, have a `toString` method.

`alert()` expects to be passed a string. Since you pass it an object, it will get converted to a string, which is done by calling `toString()`.

Comment: So, if an object is passed to alert it automatically converts it to string, with toString()?

Comment: @Yozex That's exactly what the last line of the answer says.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are not executing the function before returning anything in the second example. You are just returning a function definiton with this row: `return function (){ return x;};`. This is why the function returns just the function that you placed after the `return`.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are never called automatically. They can be passed as arguments, returned as values, assigned to variables, etc. and this just moves around references to the function. In order to call a function, you have to use the `()` operator.

Your first example does this by calling the function in the IIFE. "II" stands for "Immediately Invoked", and refers to putting `()` right after the anonymous function expression, so that you define it and then immediately invoke it.

In your second example, you simply return the function, and then pass it as an argument to `alert()`. `alert()` has no reason to call the function (it's not like `map()` or `forEach()`, which take a callback argument and are specified to call the function). If you want to execute the function, you need to call it explicitly, e.g.

```js
var foo = function() {
  var x = 5;
  return function() {
    return x;
  };
}
alert(foo()());
```

The double `()` means to first call `foo`, then call whatever it returns, and finally pass the result to `alert`.